# Hello All, I’m trying to take down the 3 walls - load bearing or not?

Tags: walls, structure

[image: attic pic]
This is the attic - and I will post the 3 walls as well- this is 1 story.[image: 3 walls we want to take down below the attic in the other pic]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard for us to know from here with so little information; can you post a house plan, or a picture of the beams over/under the walls?

Comment: Which 3 walls too?

Comment: It's going to be ver difficult to tell from any photos and depending on your location you would planning permission and a structural engineer to sign off on this...

Comment: Daniel Griscom I will try for more pics we close in a week.